# How to convert negative double to binary representation?

Tags: java, binary, double, long-integer, ieee-754

I tried a lot of tips from this site, but I can't convert a negative float or double correctly to its binary represenation. Some numbers work fine, but if I want to convert -11.1 I get the wrong bit representation.

My code:

```
public static String fromFloatTo64Binary(String input) {

    input = input.replaceAll(",", ".");

    double number = Double.parseDouble(input);
    long longBits = Double.doubleToLongBits(number);
    String result = Long.toBinaryString(longBits);

    // check if input is signed
    if (input.substring(0, 1).equalsIgnoreCase("-")) {
        result = 1 + result;
    } else {
        result = 0 + result;
    }

    return result;

}
```

Input: 11.1
Output: 0 1000000 00100110 00110011 00110011 00110011 00110011 00110011 00110011

Input: -11.1
Output: 1 1100000 00010011 00011001 10011001 10011001 10011001 10011001 10011001

Convert these bits into decimal again: -6.402228286547589E154

Comment: Why are you prepending a `0` or `1`?

Comment: Without prepending a 0 or 1 I get 63 bits. I need this for the sign.

Comment: The upper string has 63 (the front group has 7 characters). Which makes sense, since the sign bit is not set in the positive double. EDIT: Actually, the front group has 7 in both cases, which makes no sense at all. I think it's a bug in the splitting code, which is not shown.

Comment: The implementation can strip arbitrarily many leading 0s, which is not what you want.  You will have to add as many zeroes as necessary to get 64 bits, but you will never want to add a leading 1.  Otherwise this looks correct.

Comment: I'm formatting the result with MaskFormatter mf.setMask("* ******* ******** ******** ******** ******** ******** ******** ********");
    Ieee754_64.setText(mf.valueToString(result64));

Comment: Oh, okay. In that case it's just that by adding another sign bit where one already exists, you're shoving a mantissa bit one to the right where the `MaskFormatter` will no longer handle it. In essence: what @LouisWasserman says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following seems to work:

```
    input = input.replaceAll(",", ".");

    double number = Double.parseDouble(input);
    long longBits = Double.doubleToLongBits(number);
    String result = Long.toBinaryString(longBits);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = result.length(); i < 64; i++) {
        builder.append('0');
    }
    return builder.append(result).toString();
```

(IDEOne results at https://ideone.com/winQFa)

Answer (score 0):

Very well articulated by Louis Wasserman but here i am also giving a simple line code to solve this problem:-

```
 System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(Double.doubleToRawLongBits(-11.1)));
```

This issue has been discussed in depth over here as well [How to convert negative double value to binary value in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858806/how-to-convert-negative-double-value-to-binary-value-in-java)

Hope it helps . Have a great day !